# Calling Class Based View (POST) method without going through url.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, url-routing, django-class-based-views

We are developing an application backend API end points using Django Rest Framework with class based view approach.

have an end point like `BASE_URL/api/v1/users/posts/` , when called with post method all it does is saves `(posts data, ex: {"post_id" : "1", "post_content" : "some_text" ,"posted_username": "user_name"})` into back-end database.

The above end point will be processed by application `urls.py` file and will redirect to corresponding view to save the data.

I want co call the corresponding end point view class post method but not through regular end point [ `requests.post(url,data,headers)` ], I need to invoke this class post method from another python file (within the same application), without going through `urls.py`.

All I want to eliminate is network call. Please don't suggest saving directly to database by opening a connection to database, I want to save data through REST API end point only (class view post method only) but not actually calling end point.

Sample code:

```
class PosttView( mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes              =   []
    permission_classes                  =   []
    serializer_class                    =   PostSerializer
    queryset                            =   Posts.objects.all()

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.create(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Presumably all your view does is call a serializer. You could just do that directly.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your response class view makes use of serializer class. How can I do that directly I want to invoke this class view, suppose if I have code like the following.  class PosttView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,mixins.ListModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes              =   []
    permission_classes                  =   []
    serializer_class                    =   PostSerializer
    queryset                            =   Posts.objects.all()
  
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.create(request,*args,**kwargs)